# How to JOIN or UPDATE the table in SAS?

Tags: sql, join, sas

I have one table, with 3(id) is missing and in second table 1(id)& 2(id) is missing but 3(id)is present. I want to update all ids `1(id),2(id),(3(id)` in SAS only.

NOTE: I don't want to create extra column.

eg.

```
id industry
1  a
2  b
3

id industry
1  
2  
3  c

id industry
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

Comment: Be more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prepare data**

```
data a;
    infile datalines missover;
    input id industry $;
datalines;
1  a
2  b
3
;
run;

data b;
    infile datalines missover;
    input id industry $;
datalines;
1  
2  
3  c
;
run;
```

**Solution**

***method 1***

```
/* create a new data set A */
data a;
    update a b;
    by id;
run;
```

***method 2***

```
/* modificate an existing data set A (better performance)*/
data a;
    modify a b;
    by id;
run;
```